# MATLAB: How can I create autocorrelated data?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to create a vector of autocorrelated data points in MATLAB, with the lag 1 higher than lag 2, and so on.

If I look at the lag 1 data pairs (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), ..., then the correlation is relatively higher, but then at lag 2 it's reduced.

I found a way to do this in R

```
x <- filter(rnorm(1000), filter=rep(1,3), circular=TRUE)
```

However, I'm not sure how to do the same thing in MATLAB. Ideally I'd like to be able to fine tune exactly how autocorrelated the data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Math:

A group of standard models for autocorrelation in stationary time series are so called "auto regressive model" eg. an autoregressive model with 1 term is known as an AR(1) and is:

```
                              y_t = a + b*y_{t-1} + e_t
```

AR(1) sounds simplistic, but it turns it's a quite powerful tooll. Eg. an AR(p) with p autoregressive terms is actually an AR(1) on a p dimensional vector. ([Check Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model)) Note also b=1, gives a non-stationary random walk.

A more intuitive way to write what's going on (in stationary case with |b| < 1) is define `u = a / (1 - b)` (turns out `u` is unconditional mean of AR(1)), then with some algebra:

```
                    y_t - u = b * ( y_{t-1} - u) + e_t
```

That is, the difference from the unconditional mean `u` gets hit with some decay term b and then a shock term e_t gets added. (you want `-1<b<1` for stationarity)

#### Code:

Since e_t denotes the shock term, this is super easy to simulate. Eg. to simulate an AR(1):

```
a = 0; b = .4; sigma = 1; T = 1000;
y0 = a / (1 - b); %eg initialize to unconditional mean of stationary time series

y = zeros(T,1);
y(1) = a + b * y0 + randn() * sigma;
for t = 2:T
    y(t) = a + b * y(t-1) + randn() * sigma;
end
```

This code isn't mean to be fast, but illustrative. An AR(1) model implies a certain type of correlation structure, but adding AR or MA terms, you can fit some pretty funky stuff.  (MA is moving average model)

Can test sample autocorrelation with `autocorr(y)`. For reference, the bible on time series mathematics is Hamilton's book *Time Series Analysis*.

Comment: @user1205901 The number of timesteps in your series.

Comment: I get "Error using sigma - Not enough input arguments." It seems sigma an argument SYS, which the documentation says represents a "dynamic system".

Comment: I'm not using the built in MATLAB function sigma, sigma is supposed to be the standard deviation of your shock term epsilon.

Comment: This is a really good explanation and I think I'm starting to understand. However, you write "b=1, gives a non-stationary random walk". If b=1 wouldn't that create a problem because we'd be dividing by zero?

Comment: Yup.  A random walk doesn't have an *unconditional* mean! If you have y_t = y_{t-1} + e_t and ask what's E[y_t], it's undefined! I'm probably bouncing around too many topics to be super clear. A key distinction in time series analysis is whether you have a stationary time series or a non-stationary time series.

Example: GDP (gross domestic product) is probably a non-stationary random walk. On the other hand, GDP GROWTH (i.e. change in GDP) is probably a stationary time series. The economy grows on average about 2% a year. Simplest model of GDP, might be an AR(1) on changes in log GDP.

Comment: Another fun example: way back in the day, Yule-Walker used an AR(2) to model the recurrence of sunspots... they tended to have cycles of 7 years. With an AR(2), you can get not just decay but some cyclicality.

Comment: Time series mathematics is a HUGE topic. Easy to get lost, but simple AR(1) or AR(2) on scalars or vectors gets you pretty far.

Comment: I hope this isn't off-topic, but I have just one more question. Having done that simulation you coded and obtaining an autocorrelated vector y, is there some way to take that vector and "remove the autocorrelation"? I'm imagining a scenario like the one I described at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182124/how-can-i-remove-autocorrelation-from-this-data in which the only thing I have is the autocorrelated data.

Comment: @user1205901 Basic game plan is to fit a time series model (eg. AR(1), MA(1), ARMA(1,1), or ARMA(2,2) etc...) to your data y_t so that the residuals e_t aren't autocorrelated at a statistically significant level. Adding additional lag terms (eg. going from AR(1) to AR(2)) helps reduce autocorrelation in the residuals e_t. The downside of adding lag terms is increased risk of overfitting the data.

Comment: Thus the plan is: fit model, obtain parameters, and then use those parameters to attempt to regenerate the data, but now when the data is regenerated the autocorrelation will be gone, or mostly gone?

Comment: @user1205901 No... Idea is that you can use a time series model to extract some estimate of random shocks \epsilon_t.  Let's say the true data generating model is y_t = .7 y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t. \epsilon_t is WHITE NOISE time series and has no autocorrelation (eg. is just randn(T, 1)).  The time series y_t will be autocorrelated. If I estimate the the model y_t = b * y_{t-1} + e_t, I get an estimate b (hopefully around .7) but also a time series of residuals, e_t that are an estimate of the series \epsilon_t.

Comment: @user1205901 Really loose/sloppy analogy: imagine you have some time series y_t of a plane's position and some random time series e_t of random control inputs. The time series model allows you to go back and forth between the two.

Comment: I think I have some understanding of the model, but it wasn't clear to me how having an estimate of the random shocks would help me create a non-autocorrelated version of the data, or how I should program it.

Comment: @user1205901 I don't know what that really means....
Eg. if my data is a time series of my car's velocity sampled every second, what is a "non-autocorrelated version" of my car's velocity? What are you even trying to get in this case? what do you mean by removing the auto correlation? If it's not autocorrelated, it doesn't make any sense as a car's velocity

You can't set your car to a new, random velocity each second...

Comment: The context in which I'm thinking about this is people making estimates about some quantity, but then they can see the quantity the person before them estimated. I'm looking for some transformation that will try and move towards what they would have estimated if they were never influenced by contact with the person who came before them. One way to do that is to dump every second person from the sample, but I was hoping to find some statistical adjustment.